# How to resrict document editing (by owner) in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

How do you restrict document editing (by owner) in Microsoft Word?

I selected Review -> Restrict Editing (read only, applied to everyone), but I still don't see the yellow bar that says the document can't be edited, and I can still edit the document. I guess because I'm the owner?  I made the document read-only, and I can still edit it (but can't save it).  I need editing disabled so I don't accidentally start mark changes in two versions of the document.  Sometimes when I get documents from other people editing is disabled until I enable it.

I DON'T want it password protected.  The documents I get from other people, with editing disabled, don't require a password to enable editing.

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish and why? Generally, outside enterprise environments Word documents can ALWAYS be modified further, and usually without much difficulty. Converting the document to another file type is usually far more effective and commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Info -> Protect Document -> Mark as Final.

This does it. Editing is disabled.

Comment: Marking as final does not prevent making further edits. If it "solved" your problem, then you didn't do a particularly good job describing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Try selecting all of the text and applying the Group Content Control on the Developer tab.

You then will be unable to type anywhere in the document (except content controls) until you ungroup that area.

As an alternative, under Restrict Editing select the option for No Changes and the apply it without any password.